# What container should I use for multiple immutable references of a heap-allocated struct?

Tags: rust, heap-memory

Basically I have a heap-allocated `struct` `Box<State>`. I have multiple `Value` `struct`s that need to have an immutable reference to this heap-allocated `struct`.

What kind of attribute can I use inside of `Value` for this reference? Using `Rc<Box<State>>` does not work because I need `Value` to implement `Copy` and `State` does not implement `Copy`. When it needs to copy itself, I just want to copy the pointer to that heap-allocated `State`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're asking for is basically impossible. If you have many pointers to the heap allocation floating around, you need to somehow keep track of these pointers to be able to deallocate once all these pointers are destroyed. However, that requires doing *something* whenever one of the pointer is duplicated, and/or doing *something* when the pointers are destroyed.

Well, that's not quite true, there are two ways around this:

- Don't deallocate, i.e., leak memory
- Have a garbage collector periodically going through all memory that might contain pointers to the allocation.

But the first is impractical in most contexts (and quite dirty even when you can afford it), and the second has other costs and far-reaching consequences and is not really well supported in current Rust anyway.

The only sane thing is to drop the `Copy` requirement. Perhaps you're confusing `Copy` with `Clone`? The primary difference between the two is that you have to call `clone()` explicitly while `Copy` works implicitly. `Rc<anything>` is `Clone` and cloning the reference counted pointer will only increment the refcount, not clone the thing behind the pointer. (And in this case you almost certainly can and should get rid of the `Box`, since `Rc<T>` already allocates the `T` on the heap, so the `Box` is just a pointless additional indirection.)

Comment: This makes sense. I `Clone` should be enough, but I can't really wrap my head around why `Copy` can't just make one more reference until everything just runs out of scope and the `Rc` reaches 0.

Comment: @dragostis `Copy` is plain `memcpy`. It literally just copies the bits that make up the object, it *can't* do anything more fancy, and it *isn't intended to*. The C++ style "copy constructors" which do additional work to maintain invariants (e.g. a correct refcount) are represented by `Clone`.

Comment: Got it. There is one more problem: what if I have a method in the `State` that has a `&self` reference but needs to pass a `Rc<State>`?

Comment: @dragostis What do you mean? `Rc` implements the `Deref` trait, so `some_rc.normal_method()` *just works* (and when it's not a method, e.g. you have `fn foo(x: &State)`, you can call it via `foo(&state_rc)` thanks to Deref coercions).

Comment: Well, if `Value` has a `fn new(s: Rc<State>)` and I'm going to create one from a `fn func(&self) { Value::new(???) }` that's defined on `State`. How is this achievable?

Comment: @dragostis Ah, I see. This is a bit complicated. You can't just implement it on `&self`, since you need access to the `Rc` to increment the refcount (and you probably don't want to crate a whole new copy of the state every time you call `foo`). I would recommend adding a method to `Rc<State>` but this requires an "extension trait" because of coherence :( The other option is to not make it a method of `State` but rather a free function or move everything you need to do in `foo` into `Value::new`.

Comment: @dragostis if `func()` is defined on `State`, it can't use `Value::new(Rc<State>)`, because it would need to provide it `Rc<State>`, but `func()` accepts `&self` and therefore it only has `&State`. `Rc` means shared *ownership* (so you need to pass a *value* of type `T` to create `Rc<T>`), but `&` means shared *borrowing*. You can't get a value out of a shared (immutable) reference, so you can't create a new `Rc` in this situation.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev Sure, that's fine. But how can I have that immutable reference to `State` inside `Value` without having to give up on creating `Value`s in `State` methods? A very simple solution would be to just NOT have a reference in `Value` and implement all the functions in `State`, but that way I would turn the whole thing into a god class.

Comment: For your second problem about having a `fn func(&self) { Value::new(???) }`, you can make the function take a `self: &Rc<Self>` instead. See an example on the [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f19d715c7213fb106c87c4b5706c605f)